# how do /var/spool/(clientmqueue,mqueue,mail) work?

Tags: linux, routing, cron, sendmail

If - for example - cron jobs output to stdout, which is the  process collecting the output and writing to these directories ?

> /var/spool/clientmqueue
>   /var/spool/mqueue
>   /var/spool/mail

Where can I find docs on the inner details (pipe, rpc, ...) of the "redirection" from stdout to mail files ?

If I send an email whith sendmail, does it do the same routing as above ? docs ?

Comment: If you run any mta process than it will write the mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I rename the sendmail true executable

> /usr/sbin/sendmail

and replaced it with this bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/var/log/sendmail_calledby.log
date >> $LOGFILE
cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline | tr '\0' ' ' >> $LOGFILE
echo >> $LOGFILE
echo $* >> $LOGFILE
```

The first fish caught in the net is **CROND**